# HGETALL and HKEYS do not respond even though HGET gives me data

Tags: hash, redis

I inserted some binary data packed with MessagePack into Redis Hash.
I checked that the data is inserted by redis console "monitor".

The problem here is I can't find those data with HGETALL, HKEYS or HVALS,
even though HGET gives me the data.

$ redis-cli -h localhost
redis localhost:6379> HGETALL check;
(empty list or set)
redis localhost:6379> HKEYS check;
(empty list or set)
redis localhost:6379> HVALS check;
(empty list or set)
redis localhost:6379> HGET check "¥x96¥01¥xcd¥x1f¥xc2¥xcd¥x068¥xce¥x00¥x0fB¥xe2¥xcd¥x02R¥xce¥x00¥xb5¥x13¥x10"
"1380790800*

Is there anything I misunderstand about these commands or is this related with binary
issue, which I read redis is binary safe.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

; is not a separator.

```
HGETALL check;
```

will try to retrieve key "check;" and not "check".